# Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypeMappingSourceDependencies'

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-6.0

When I'm trying **Add-Migration**, following error was occurred.

I'm using,

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.3">
     <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
     <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.28" />
<PackageReference Include="MySql.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />
```

Exception is,

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate
    Build started...
    Build succeeded.
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
          Entity Framework Core 6.0.3 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'MySql.EntityFrameworkCore:6.0.0+MySQL8.0.28' with options: None
    System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypeMappingSourceDependencies' while attempting to activate 'MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLTypeMappingSource'.
```

Complete error log available in [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rib3xheqMS83wGcnlt3rs5wIum_WSswU/view?usp=sharing) file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please share your DI set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops! I forgot to update the answer.
I moved from **MySql.EntityFrameworkCore** to **Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql**.

Now I'm able to do following Add-Migration and Update-Database commands

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

Try to add following reference:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.1" />
```

Comment: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` is one of the dependencies of [`MySql.EntityFrameworkCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.EntityFrameworkCore/) so there is no need to install in explicitly.