# Migration System.InvalidOperationException using EF MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to perform a first EF migration of database, but I get this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypeMappingSourceDependencies' while attempting to activate 'MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLTypeMappingSource'.
```

I upped stacktrace at imgur:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv7Se.jpg

I'm using jetbrains rider (but isn't working at Visual Studio 2022 as well) and this nuget packets:
**mysql.entityframeworkcore/6.0.1** and **microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design/6.0.1**

The command line I used was:
**dotnet ef migrations AddInitialMigration**

My entire code is:

```
namespace LibraryDB.db;
internal class CatalogueContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> catalogue { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=libraryDB2;user=username;password=password");
    }
}

##### 

namespace LibraryDB;
public class Book
{
   [Key]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Publisher { get; set; }
}
```

I already searched over all internet, but i can't get a resolution for that. Please help-me!

Comment: *I already searched over all internet* What about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71788596/861716 (and there are more with the same exception).

Comment: @GertArnold With Pomelo Packet didn't worked as well, unfortunately.

Comment: https://davecallan.com/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-error/

Answer (score 0):

I discovered by myself a resolution for that problem. Creating a DbContext by Command Line to MySQL database connection, I finally get a migration:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=localhost;User Id=youruser;Password=yourpassword;Database=yourdatabase" "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" -c MyDbContext
```

I'm going to close question now. Thank you everyone.